# Android 11 not showing WhatsApp status in app. /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/ folder shows empty result

Tags: android, whatsapp, status, android-11

In my app, i am fetching WhatsApp status from /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/ folder everything working fine till Android 10, but in android 11 it shows nothing. Please guild me for this.
app showing status till 29 when change tp 30 folder show nothing.

Comment: android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

add this to your manifest

although google wont allow u to upload the app to play store

Comment: This won't work and is misleading because `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not for that

Answer (score 0):

The Status directory has changed to `/Android/media/com.whatsapp/.Statuses` due to the new changes of Android 11 which do not give access to External Storage as freely as before Android versions

You can read about the changes [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) in
detail

To summarise the exact cause of this change, is the WhatsApp was previously using the External Storage by creating it's own folder and that is not possible with the new scoped storage without requesting the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Google will usually reject your app on the playstore if you request this permission. So WhatsApp has moved all of its required stuff in the above directory since the `Android/data/` directory is no longer accessible and they want the user to access all of this data

There is an Android App which accesses the WhatsApp status directory and you can find it [here](https://github.com/GauthamAsir/WhatsApp_Status_Saver)

Comment: the path at which my phone saves the status is /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses/ so how can i access /Android/media/com.whatsapp/.Statuses also i cant add android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" this permission as app wont upload on playstore and the second reason is statuses also not showning even adding this permission .. i am also following the link that you have provided

Comment: The path has changed for Android 10+ to above and it remains the same below Android 10. Maybe your device is A10 or above.

Comment: it is working fine compileSdkVersion 29 targetSdkVersion 29 statuses are showing but at targetSdkVersion 30 nothing shows debuger shows list size 0

Comment: my phone is android 11

Comment: Check edited answer and don't repeat what you've asked in the question in the comments

Comment: I changed my directory as you said but this time directory cant find. I have also checked the directory via computer where statuses are saving and that was the path I have mention above now how can we tackle this thing

Answer (score 0):

Let the user pick  the directory with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.